# CPPFlags in config.mk

Tags: linux, compilation, makefile, flags

In Arch Linux PKGBUILD for surf browser, there is:

```
sed -i 's/CPPFLAGS =/CPPFLAGS +=/g' config.mk
sed -i 's/CFLAGS =/CFLAGS +=/g' config.mk
sed -i 's/LDFLAGS =/LDFLAGS +=/g' config.mk
```

Why must the flags be changed from

```
CPPFLAGS = -DVERSION=\"${VERSION}\"
```

to

```
CPPFLAGS += -DVERSION=\"${VERSION}\"
```

I've looked into google, but don't see anything there about this. Can someone please explain and tell me where to read more about these flags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did quite a lot of googling and found that this pattern (Surf's is [here](http://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/community.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/surf)) seems fairly common in Arch Linux PKGBUILD files. Another example was in [DWM's PKGBUILD](https://github.com/tvale/dwm/blob/372461d1597fff80180a5860c0365c5d60105cf5/PKGBUILD).

Obviously it is patching the [`config.mk`](http://hg.suckless.org/surf/file/2533f186089d/config.mk) file so that when `make` is called, the values are appended to the flags instead of overriding the flags (which must already be set elsewhere). So there must be existing settings that need to be retained. This seems to just be done by default by the package builders so it was hard to find the reason.

Looking further I found [this bug report](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/19815) relating to DWM's `config.mk` file, where the author notes that a version of that file was overriding flags set in `makepkg.conf` which is the [main configuration file for `makepkg`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Makepkg), which allows tuning compilation settings per machine. This seems like a reasonable explanation for what you found. From that page, a default value for `CFLAGS` would be something like this:

```
CFLAGS="-march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe"
```

So the patched `config.mk` file would result in the following when building the package:

```
CFLAGS="-march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Os -I. ....."
```

Comment: Thank you @Ben Scott. I accpet your answer as I don't have reputation to upvote. But I don't understand "appending values to the flags rather than just setting the flags outright." But it gives me more to google, thanks.

Comment: @Edouard I expanded my answer a bit to explain what gets appended